# split and get specific cell in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have object that named: flight.flight_number

flight.flight_number = a11;g73;jb87;dd45;

flight.flight_name= London;Berlin;Torino;Rome;

its separate his values by ';'

I have this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(flight.flight_number) track by $index">
  {{flight.flight_name.split(';')[ {{$index}}]}}
</div>

 $scope.getNumber = function (num) {
          var arr = num.split(';');
          var count = arr.length;
          return new Array(count-1);
      }
```

its not works because [ {{$index}}] is not properly written...

if i change [ {{$index}}] to some number (for example [4]) it works

whats wrong in here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js code:

```
 $scope.arr = flight.flight_number.split(';');
```

Html code:

```
   <div ng-repeat="i in arr">
     {{i}}
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$index is the index of your ng-repeat where as split return your array like this. $index and split have no direct connection.

```
[London, Berlin, Torino, Rome]
```

Comment: so what do i need to do?